Is there a way to fix invalid JSON records where escape characters were removed?
There was a bug in our code where we accidentally removed all escape characters from our JSON, causing the records to be invalid. Our original looks like this where the metadata field contains a stringified JSON object.
{
    "id": "123ab",
    "operation": "foo",
    "metadata": "{\"source\": \"ddb\", \"destination\": \"s3\"}",
    "data": "02-02-2024"
}

After parsing it, the metadata field becomes invalid.
{
    "id": "123ab",
    "operation": "foo",
    "metadata": "{"source": "ddb", "destination": "s3"}",
    "data": "02-02-2024"
}

Is there a way to take this invalid JSON and fix the metadata field manually? Fixing it from the source is not an option unfortunately.

you mean you removed the escaping ( the backslash ) just from the keys and values of nested entries right ?

Yes. Basically, my original intention was to remove any backslashes from the JSON object. For example, "operation": "fo\o" would turn into "operation": "foo". But I did not realize there could be a field in the records that holds a JSON object as a string (i.e metadata field). So just wondering if there is a way to re-stringify the metadata field to turn the value back into a string manually.

Do you want the escaping to just work potentially via specification of your json string payload as and r-string? Or are you asking how to make the value of the key "metadata" a dictionary?

If the JSON actually looks like the top snippet, where each key is on a different line, then this could be done.   If it is compressed JSON, then it might not actually be possible.

@TimRoberts I see. So you're saying if the JSON also contains a (non-stringified) nested object such as:
{"person":{"name":"James","age":23}}
It's probably impossible to fix it?

@JonSG Yeah, I just want to add the escaping backslash back into the metadata value to turn it back into a string.

Well, "impossible" is a harsh word.  If you processed it character by character and counted up quotes and braces, it might be do-able.  Let me play with it.

Aside: A better design would just set the metadata key directly to the dictionary {'source': 'ddb', 'destination': 's3'} before generating JSON.  Why embed JSON strings in the JSON?

@MarkTolonen that would definitely be ideal but the snippet I showed is just a sample object for easy reading. The application itself is very complex and requires us to embed some JSON objects as a string.

I haven't done extensive corner-case testing, but I think this does what you need.  Basically, if we see an open brace inside a double-quoted string, then we start escaping any quotes until we see the closed brace.
This could be fooled by pathological inputs, but I'm not sure there's a general-case answer.
import json

s = '{"id": "123ab","operation": "foo","metadata": "{"source": "ddb", "destination": "s3"}","data": "02-02-2024"}'

# So, if we get a curly brace inside a quote, all quote marks need to be escaped
# until we see the matching close brace.


out = ''
brace = 0
quote = 0
for c in s:
    if c == '{' and quote:
        brace += 1
    if c == '"':
        if brace:
            out += '\\'
        quote = 1 - quote
    if c == '}' and quote:
        brace -= 1
    out += c

print(out)

Output:
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ python x.py | jq
{
  "id": "123ab",
  "operation": "foo",
  "metadata": "{\"source\": \"ddb\", \"destination\": \"s3\"}",
  "data": "02-02-2024"
}


Thank you! I'm also hoping there aren't any edge cases. But this should be sufficient to help me get started. Appreciate the help!
